# how to fix the following small fragments of java code

Tags: java, arrays

so i am trying to create an arraySet from only an array and array methods. I have the following piece of code that should find the index of the item chosen (i've included comments so you can understand what each method is supposed to do). As you can see the add method calls on the findIndex method before it can add the item. The problem i am having is that the findIndex method brings up an error (missing return value). How would i return just the int index of the item that the code finds? (the question marks in the code are just to show where i am stuck)

```
/** Find the index of an element in the dataarray, or -1 if not present
 *  Assumes that the item is not null 
 */
private int findIndex(Object item) {

    for(int i=0; i<data.length;i++){
        if(data[i] == item){
            return i;
        }

    }
  return ???
}


/** Add the specified element to this set (if it is not a duplicate of an element
 *  already in the set).
 *  Will not add the null value (throws an IllegalArgumentException in this case)
 *  Return true if the collection changes, and false if it did not change.
 */
public boolean add(E item) {


    if(item == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    else if(contains(item) == true){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    else{

        int index = findIndex(item);
        if(index<0||index>count){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(); 
       }
        ensureCapacity();
        for(int i=count; i>index; i--){
            data[i]=data[i-1];
        }
        data[index] = item;
        count++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: homework, perchance? then tag it as such

Comment: ¿Didn't you answer yourself in the code comments? Shouldn't it return -1 when no match is found?

Comment: Are you trying to make something like CopyOnWriteArraySet? Or ArrayList which ignores duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question right it should just be this, the 'return i' accomplishes what you are asking, the return -1 is for the not found case:

```
private int findIndex(Object item) {

  for(int i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i] == item){
        return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: ah ok, thats initially what i had but it didnt seem to run correctly, I must have made other errors in my code, thank you for your help.

Comment: You probably want a semicolon at the end of your return statment :)

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question, for the most part, in your comments.  Which integer *should* be returned when the item can't be found?  It can't be a valid value for something in the collection (think 0 <= x < list.size()).

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

A method that is declared to return a value *must* either return a value or throw an exception, no matter what. In the code you've written so far, you return a value only when you actually find what you're looking for. What should the method do when you *don't* find what you're looking for? It needs to return something then, too.

What is often done is to return a special value that couldn't possibly be an index. Hint: what kind of integers are never used as array indexes in Java? Return one of those. Then document this choice, and code that calls your method will have to check for this special return value to see if the item was found or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the `return i` in the middle of your loop, as you currently have.

But you also need a return statement in case that if statement is never reached. Since your comment says you should use -1, you need a `return -1` where you have `return ???`

Comment: Why was I downvoted? I would like to be able to improve my answers for the future.

Comment: If it's a homework question, you don't want to give the answer explicitly.  Check [How to Ask and Answer Homework Questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/175248)

Comment: You're assuming that it's a homework question and down-voting based on that assumption, which could very well be wrong.  For all we know he's troubleshooting code someone else wrote. Read the link you posted: "Don't downvote others who answer homework questions in good faith, even if they break these guidelines. It's not always obvious at first glance that a question is homework, especially when you're not expecting to see it here. It is a good idea to suggest editing the response in a comment."

Comment: @Makoto It does not seem obvious to me that it is homework. Personally, I think it might not be. But I understand your point and will be mindful of it in the future.